# How synchronization with a remote node works?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, synchronization, windows

I'm using a remote node, but it says disconnected so I clicked start Deamon and I'm waiting so much time for it to synchronize and it's filling my disk space ?

I was thinking it do not fill disk space and connect instantly if it's using and remote node.

It should work like that or it's using local node for some reason

Comment: Start daemon will start the local node. Also, which version of the GUI are you using?

Comment: @dEBRUYNE v0.12.3.0   
To start connect using a remote node I should go to settings type the address and port and click connect and network status should change to connected ? I'm doing so and it keeps to be Disconnected

Comment: Yes and make sure the wallet mode is set to remote node. A more graphical guide can be found here -> https://getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/remote_node_gui.html. As a side note, to which remote node are you trying to connect?

Comment: @dEBRUYNE eu.node.moneroworld.com 18089

Comment: @dEBRUYNE When I start gui it says Starting local node in 9seconds. Just tried opennode.xmr-tw.org  can't connect as well.

Comment: Could you try `node.moneroworld.com` with port `18089`?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comments above:

When using a remote node, you are using it's daemon and downloaded blockchain. If you cannot connect to a remote node, you can run the local daemon. This then needs to download the blockchain to your local machine. Depending on how fast your connection is and whether your disk is a spinning HD or SSD, this can take from hours to a week.

It's also worth noting that when using a remote node that is not your own remote node, you are trusting the remote node operator and thus can lose some security and privacy.

A common and very useful reason to run your own remote node is when you have multiple devices that you wish to use Monero with and don't want to trust someone elses remote node. For example, run a simple cloud server as your own full remote node, secure access to the daemon using something like stunnel, SSH tunnel or proxied Apache/Nginx using SSL. Then you can use your own remote node from other devices like your phone / laptop etc without having the overhead of the ~70GB blockchain on each device.